# Javascript button already pressed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I'm trying to make a button function that add a field to a form, but when I load the page the field it's already there and the button is useless.

Here's the HTML and JS code

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
let code_2 = document.querySelector(".code2")

btn.addEventListener("click", add())

function add() {
  code_2.innerHTML += '<br><label>Segundo código:</label><br><br><input type="text"><br><br><button id="btn2">Adicionar Peça</button>'
}
```

```html
<div class="pecas">

  <div class="peca">

    <h2>Primeira Peça:</h2>
    <form>
      <label>Primeiro código:</label><br><br>
      <input type="text"><br><br>
      <button id="btn">Adicionar Peça</button>

      <div class="code2">

      </div>


    </form>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `btn.addEventListener("click", add())` runs add immediately ... you want `btn.addEventListener("click", add)`

Comment: If i do this it works, but the button shows up and vanishes immediately

Comment: because a button inside a form submits the form unless you make it `type="button"`